# downloading all files from sftp server in java

Tags: java, sftp, jsch, private-key

I am trying to Download All files from folder on SFTP server , Below is my Code Please suggest changes so i can download All available files from remote directory and can save to Local Directory

```
package svb.ftp.bs.load;

import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import java.util.Vector;

public class downloadFtp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String SFTPHOST = "host";
        int SFTPPORT = 22;
        String SFTPUSER = "user";
        String SFTPPASS = "Pass";
        String privateKey = "E:\\Oracle\\mywork\\DownloadFTP\\ppk.ppk";
        String SFTPWORKINGDIR = "Inbox/ARR_SI_MedicalTranscriptionBillCorp_PD_20200724_32137.TXT";

        com.jcraft.jsch.Session session = null;
        Channel channel = null;
        ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        try {
            jsch.addIdentity(privateKey);
            session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER, SFTPHOST, SFTPPORT);
            session.setPassword(SFTPPASS);
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
            channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            System.out.println("Connected");
            channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR);

            
            InputStream is = channelSftp.get(SFTPWORKINGDIR);
            IOUtils.copy(is, System.out);
            is.close();


            System.out.println("File Uploaded to FTP Server Sucessfully.");
        } catch (JSchException jse) {
            // TODO: Add catch code
            jse.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SftpException se) {
            // TODO: Add catch code
            se.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       

    }
}
```

Currently when i run the code it show below error

```
4: Can't change directory: /Inbox/ARR_SI_MedicalTranscriptionBillCorp_PD_20200724_32137.TXT
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.cd(ChannelSftp.java:350)
    at svb.ftp.bs.load.downloadFtp.main(downloadFtp.java:67)
Process exited with exit code 0.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stacktrace is telling you what's wrong.

> Can't change directory: /Inbox/ARR_SI_MedicalTranscriptionBillCorp_PD_20200724_32137.TXT

Problem is with:

```
channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR);
```

Here you are passing filename but its expecting a directory (`cd` stands for Change Directory). You cannot do CD to a file.

If you pass a folder/path it would work. Try the following :

```
channelSftp.cd("/Inbox/a_folder/");
```

---

**How to Download All:**
Reference: https://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2020/07/download-files-from-ftp-using-jsch-java.html

In order to download all files, first list all files in root folder, iterate over it.. if its a file download, if its a folder list the content and keep doing it recursively for sub folders.

**The following is an example of how to download files from a defined folder:**

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Vector;

public class JschDownload {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Session session = null;
        Channel channel = null;
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        try {
            session = jsch.getSession("demo", "test.rebex.net", 22);
            session.setPassword("password");
            Properties config = new Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
            System.out.println("session connect");


            channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            System.out.println("Connected");

            ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            downloadFromFolder(channelSftp, "/");
            downloadFromFolder(channelSftp, "/pub/example/");

            System.out.println("File Uploaded to FTP Server Sucessfully.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            if (channel != null) {
                channel.disconnect();
            }
            session.disconnect();
        }

    }

    static void downloadFromFolder(ChannelSftp channelSftp, String folder) throws SftpException {
        Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> entries = channelSftp.ls(folder);
        System.out.println(entries);

        //download all from root folder
        for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry en : entries) {
            if (en.getFilename().equals(".") || en.getFilename().equals("..") || en.getAttrs().isDir()) {
                continue;
            }

            System.out.println(en.getFilename());
            channelSftp.get(folder + en.getFilename(), en.getFilename());
        }
    }

}
```

Refer to http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ for examples and documentation of the jsch library.

Comment: ok , how i can download all files present `Inbox` folder

Comment: `LsEntry` is not found

Comment: Where to set Target folder path to download file

Comment: LsEntry is defined in 'com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp' package. Add the following import statement ``import  com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.*;``

Comment: It works fine ! however don't know how to get download all these files and place in local folder as it only listing the files

Comment: You can use ``channelSftp.get(`` to download a LsEntry. I just updated the answer.

Comment: `2: Cannot find message [/Inbox/-rw-------   1 200      100           950 Jun 09 18:23 OT0428.txt.20200609201738875]
` found this error

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: `2: Cannot find message [/Inbox/-rw-------   1 200      100           229 Jul 28 12:45 ARR_SI_MedicalTranscriptionBillCorp_PD_20200728_84030.TXT]
 at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2873)
 at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2225)
 at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2242)
 at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:928)
 at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:888)
 at svb.ftp.bs.load.downloadFtp.main(downloadFtp.java:77)`

Comment: Trying to download like this 

`channelSftp.get(entry.getLongname(), "E:\\" + File.separator + entry.getFilename());`

Comment: see the updated code. It uses a public ftp https://test.rebex.net/

Comment: I have updated the Code but its now showing 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at svb.ftp.bs.load.downloadFtp.downloadFromFolder(downloadFtp.java:101)
 at svb.ftp.bs.load.downloadFtp.main(downloadFtp.java:70)
`

Answer (score 0):

here a recursive methode to get all files in sub folder also

```
private void downloadFromFolder( String remotePath, String localPath ) throws SftpException {
     try
     {
    Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> entries = channel.ls(remotePath);
    System.out.println(entries);

    //download all from root folder
    for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry en : entries) {
        if(!en.getFilename().equals(".") && !en.getFilename().equals("..") && en.getAttrs().isDir())
        {
            Path path = Paths.get(localPath + "\\" + en.getFilename());
            Files.createDirectories(path);
            downloadFromFolder(remotePath + "/" + en.getFilename(),path.toString());
            continue;
        }
        if (en.getFilename().equals(".") || en.getFilename().equals("..")) {
            continue;
        }

        System.out.println(en.getFilename());
        channel.get(remotePath + "/" + en.getFilename(), localPath + "\\" + en.getFilename());
    }
     }catch(Exception e)
     {
         
     }
}
```